# Hypernym for "increase" and "decrease"

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs, hypernyms

Is there a word in English which would encompass both the action of increasing or decreasing [the value of] something?

I am looking at a word similar to *modify*, *change* or *alter*. But the first two do not denote the fact that the current value would be slightly changed and I feel the the last one is a bit general.

Comment: The verb *change* carries with it no connotation of degree. You can change something a little or a lot, and in a positive or negative direction. An antonym for *to change* would be *to stay the same*, so it appears you have your answer.

Comment: I would like to where you have intended (now decided) to use the word: the sentence and the context.

Comment: At the end I decided to use two separate words (increase and decrease) because using the proposed hypernym (vary) would bring more confusion than using the two separate terms (as I had to use it).

Comment: How about: Delta, or variance.

Comment: Fluctuate, fluctuation, depending on context, I like variance too

Comment: I wound up going with `(in/de)crease` to keep it concise xD

Answer (score 12, accepted):

One such word (and one commonly used by scientists) is *vary*.

Like *increase* and *decrease*, it is not explicit whether *vary* is an action performed on the variable, or something that the variable "just does".

> You should vary the input voltage and observe the result.

Answer (score 3):

***variation***

Typically in technical usage, variation represents change: variations in voltage, current, so on. Moreover, while variation *can* mean drastic changes, it is typically associated with small differences in state, discrete or continuous.

Comment: Yes, or the verb form, *vary*.

Answer (score 1):

If you specifically want to imply that the changes are small, vary is not entirely apt. I'd go with **tweak** "a fine adjustment to a mechanism or system" instead. Not to be confused with twerk, of course.

Answer (score 1):

**Adjust.**

I arrived here because I had the same question. I was looking for a concise word to describe a behavior of incrementing or decrementing the value of a numeric control (I was writing code), because I was making this behavior into a class for reuse.

Because I wanted a word that also conveys the fact that the behavior moves the value from its original value a relatively small amount and it does so without discontinuities, I was coming up with words like modify, or change. Value also seems pretty good.

Ultimately I ended up deciding on 'Adjust', and because I didn't see adjust suggested yet, and I thought someone else might find it helpful, I decided to add it as an answer.

Comment: I don't think adjust fits most cases. It has a very narrow contextual meaning